# Running a Windows service on machine startup

Tags: python, windows, windows-services

I have a Windows service written with Python. I want to start it automatically when the machine starts.

How can I do that?

```
class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
_svc_name_ = "Service"
_svc_display_name_ = "Myservice"

def __init__(self,args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
    #socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop) 

def SvcDoRun(self):
    servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_,''))
    self.timeout = 120000
    self.main()              #//thread.start_new_thread(main)

def main(self):
        pass

def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
    return True         

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Comment: out of curiosity, and as I don't have experience with services - what does the code above do?

Comment: I don't understand. Services run at system startup.

Comment: Your installer needs to set the service start type to Automatic (or the user can do it manually).

Comment: Changing starting type to automatic is worked. The problem was starting the main part as a threat. When I make the changes up here problem solved. thanks.

Comment: Note: I guess some of the services starting after user login but some basic ones are starting before. For example winlogon. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: And @Jonathan it's a service written with pyhton which is doing nothing. Just for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try the task scheduler:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569